# Cheating auto-shutoff of power bank

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I am trying to cheat the auto-shutoff feature of a commercial [power bank](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00J93R7XM/ref=sxbs_sxwds-stvp_1?pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_p=5256821922083943357&pd_rd_wg=BhmCr&pf_rd_r=3PATE5A04RH3QFAF166G&pf_rd_s=desktop-sx-bottom-slot&pf_rd_t=301&pd_rd_i=B00J93R7XM&pd_rd_w=bWU29&pf_rd_i=power%20bank&pd_rd_r=bc226190-8af5-47e2-b468-2cbcc3dafd42&ie=UTF8&qid=1527832643&sr=1), something along the lines of these [instructions](https://www.dorkbotpdx.org/blog/paul/battery_pack_load).

Contrary to the article I am simply using one port of an Attiny85 to output several types of pulse trains. The port is switching the load (R=60 ohms is what I have proven to keep the power bank alive when driven continuously) by means of a MOSFET (BS170). The circuit as such works as expected (proven with a DSO), but the conditions under which it keeps the power bank alive are tricky.

[image: Schematic]

- My first attempt - ordinary PWM at 1 kHz with duty cycle up to ~20% failed. I didn't drive it to higher duty cycles because my goal is saving power.
- My second attempt - manually switching the port at low frequency (<< 1 Hz) with on-time ~1 second, off-time ~4 seconds was successful
- Third attempt - reducing on-time to 0.5 seconds or increasing off-time to more than 4 seconds failed (1 second "on" seems like the minimum for the power bank to recognise intermitting load)
- Fourth attempt - on/off = 1 s/8 s with intermittent 10 ms pulses works for some time (longer than the auto-shutoff time of ~15 s), but eventually fails (shuts off)

What I conclude from these findings:

- the power bank's controller somehow integrates current (otherwise the high load peaks of the ordinary 1 kHz peaks would be enough to keep the unit awake)
- 20%-duty cycle at 1kHz (not working) is not the same as 20% duty cycle at 0.2 Hz (working), so the power bank integrating current cannot be the whole story
- the sensitivity to peak load seems to get lower for longer pauses (8 seconds), but can be reactivated by very short maximum load peaks

**Does anyone know something about commonly used strategies for implementing the auto-shutoff in commercial power banks?**

**Is there any easy explanation for the behavior that I have observed?**

**Any ideas on how I could reduce the duty cycle substantially further while keeping the unit alive?**

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and accept it to mark it solved if you don't get any good answers. Good work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post it as an answer, but I would rather wait if somebody has an answer that provides some more in depth info about these battery controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I have found out that increasing the on-time to slightly above 1 second (1.25 seconds) allows me to choose an off-time (11.75 seconds) much closer to the auto-shutoff time (~15 seconds). My guess is that the occasional failures with 1 second on-time are due to the on-time being somehow disadvantageously timed against the sampling time of the battery controller that measures current.

My best optimized version is now, on: 1.3 seconds, off: 11.7 seconds (that is a duty cycle of 10%, couldn't get it any lower), meaning total cycle time of 13 seconds. I have decided to keep some reasonable safety distance to the regular auto-shutoff time of 15 seconds. Otherwise slight variations in the parameters (due to e.g. temperature) might cause the circuit to fail occasionally/randomly.

With 10% duty cycle and 60 ohms I have now ~8 mA on average which means my 10 Ah battery will last max ~1.5 months which is quite okay.

See the corresponding Arduino sketch below. Although the values are likely to be very specific for my power bank model, I hope it saves somebody some work by giving a reasonable starting point. Remember that the Arduino software has to have the right config files for Attiny85 for correct timing and pin numbers.

```
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
  delay(1300);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  delay(11700);
}
```